# "Error: The table already has a header, add additional rows to the existing table header instead" in PDFjs, but how?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I get the mentioned error with this code :

```
const productTable = doc.table({ widths:colWidths });
const productHeader = productTable.header({ colspan: colWidths.length });

productHeader.cell({ paddingTop: 0.25 * pdf.cm }).text( productName );

const itemsHeader = productTable.header();

...
```

So, I assume that I can't add more headers, but since `productTable.header` already returns a row, therefore `productTable.header().row()` throws because there is no function `row`, how do I add more rows to a table header?

**Update** : this question is linked to [this Github issue](https://github.com/rkusa/pdfjs/issues/272), still no resolution.